# Unknown space on my hard drive

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted

I recently formatted a 250GB SSD and installed Ubuntu 14.04. I see 15GB not being used and marked as "unknown". I had not partitioned the drive initially. Can I use this space or should I just leave it?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of where you see this and upload it imgur and then edit your question to include the link to the picture? That would help us a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be your SWAP partition. It's used as a sort of overflow for your RAM so could improve performance. I'd leave it.

Comment: That's doubtful. It would normally be marked as a swap partition, not Unknown.